# Is object remain fixed when scrolling background in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have one question when infinite background scrolling is done, is the object remain fixed(like doodle in doodle jump, papy in papi jump) or these object really moves.Is only background move or both (background and object )move.plz someone help me.I am searching for this solution for 4/5 days,but can't get the solution.So plz someone help me. And if object does not move how to create such a illusion of object moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the object to the same layer as the scrolling background, then it will scroll as the background scrolls.

If your looking for an effect like the hero in doodle jump, you may want to look at having two or more layers in a scene.

1. Layer 1:  Scrolling Background Layer
2. Layer 2:  Sprite layer

SomeScene.m

```
CCLayer *backgroundLayer = [[CCLayer alloc] init];
CCLayer *spriteLayer= [[CCLayer alloc] init];

[self addChild:backgroundLayer z:0];
[self addChild:spriteLayer z:1];

//Hero stays in one spot regardless of background scrolling.
CCSprite *squidHero = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"squid.png"];
[spriteLayer addChild:squidHero];
```

If you want objects to scroll with the background add it to the background layer:

```
//Platform moves with background.
CCSprite *bouncePlatform= [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"bouncePlatform.png"];
[backgroundLayer addChild:bouncePlatform];
```

Comment: Ok,Thanks.But how to synchronize these 2 different layer.Because I have to figure out the collision between  doodle and platform.which are different layer.And how to run these 2 layer at the same time.So far i have used only one layer ,so how to run 2 layer together and check collision.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a CCFollow action. You would code as if the background is static (which it will be) and the player is moving (which it will be), but add a CCFollow action to the player. This essentially moves the camera so that it tracks your player.

You can also modify the classes so that you can get the CCFollow action to follow with an offset (i.e., so the player is not in the middle of the screen) as well as to have a smoothing effect to it, so that when the player moves, the follow action is not jerky. See the below code:

*NOTE I am using cocos2d-x, the c++ port. The methods are similar in cocos2d, and you should be able to modify these to fit the cocos2d syntax. Or search around -- I found these for cocos2d and then ported to c++.

```
//defines the action to constantly follow the player (in my case, "runner.p_sprite is the sprite pointing to the player)
FollowWithOffset* followAction = FollowWithOffset::create(runner.p_sprite, CCRectZero);
runAction(followAction);
```

And separately, I have copied the class definition for CCFollow to create my own class, CCFollowWithAction. This also has a smoothing effect (you can look this up more online) so that when the player moves, the actions are not jerky. I modified "initWithTarget," to take into account an offset, and "step," to add a smoothing action. You can see the modifications in the comments below.

```
bool FollowWithOffset::initWithTarget(CCNode *pFollowedNode, const CCRect& rect/* = CCRectZero*/)
{
    CCAssert(pFollowedNode != NULL, "");

    pFollowedNode->retain();
    m_pobFollowedNode = pFollowedNode;
    if (rect.equals(CCRectZero))
    {
        m_bBoundarySet = false;
    }
    else
    {
        m_bBoundarySet = true;
    }

    m_bBoundaryFullyCovered = false;

    CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
    m_obFullScreenSize = CCPointMake(winSize.width, winSize.height);

    //m_obHalfScreenSize = ccpMult(m_obFullScreenSize, 0.5f);
    m_obHalfScreenSize = CCPointMake(m_obFullScreenSize.x/2 + RUNNER_FOLLOW_OFFSET_X,
                                     m_obFullScreenSize.y/2 + RUNNER_FOLLOW_OFFSET_Y);

    if (m_bBoundarySet)
    {
        m_fLeftBoundary = -((rect.origin.x+rect.size.width) - m_obFullScreenSize.x);
        m_fRightBoundary = -rect.origin.x ;
        m_fTopBoundary = -rect.origin.y;
        m_fBottomBoundary = -((rect.origin.y+rect.size.height) - m_obFullScreenSize.y);

        if(m_fRightBoundary < m_fLeftBoundary)
        {
            // screen width is larger than world's boundary width
            //set both in the middle of the world
            m_fRightBoundary = m_fLeftBoundary = (m_fLeftBoundary + m_fRightBoundary) / 2;
        }
        if(m_fTopBoundary < m_fBottomBoundary)
        {
            // screen width is larger than world's boundary width
            //set both in the middle of the world
            m_fTopBoundary = m_fBottomBoundary = (m_fTopBoundary + m_fBottomBoundary) / 2;
        }

        if( (m_fTopBoundary == m_fBottomBoundary) && (m_fLeftBoundary == m_fRightBoundary) )
        {
            m_bBoundaryFullyCovered = true;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void FollowWithOffset::step(float dt)
{
    CC_UNUSED_PARAM(dt);

    if(m_bBoundarySet){
        // whole map fits inside a single screen, no need to modify the position - unless map boundaries are increased
        if(m_bBoundaryFullyCovered)
            return;

        CCPoint tempPos = ccpSub( m_obHalfScreenSize, m_pobFollowedNode->getPosition());

        m_pTarget->setPosition(ccp(clampf(tempPos.x, m_fLeftBoundary, m_fRightBoundary), 
                                   clampf(tempPos.y, m_fBottomBoundary, m_fTopBoundary)));
    }
    else{
        //custom written code to add in support for a smooth ccfollow action
        CCPoint tempPos = ccpSub( m_obHalfScreenSize, m_pobFollowedNode->getPosition());
        CCPoint moveVect = ccpMult(ccpSub(tempPos,m_pTarget->getPosition()),0.25); //0.25 is the smooth constant.
        CCPoint newPos = ccpAdd(m_pTarget->getPosition(), moveVect);
        m_pTarget->setPosition(newPos);
    }
}
```